# Where to start for a web application?

Tags: node.js

I want to start and learn coding to create a web application. I have experience in Java, C, Lisp, and Perl. I heard node.js is good to learn.
Can anyone suggest a good place to start?

Comment: Do you have a particular problem you are trying to solve or something you are trying to accomplish with a web application?

Comment: To start, a chat application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to learn javascript. Pedro Teixeira makes node screencasts which you can watch it at http://nodetuts.com/. Just sit back, relax and watch these screencasts to learn about nodejs.

Furthermore I would advice you to master:

- [npm](http://npmjs.org/): npm is a package manager for node
- [expressjs.com](http://expressjs.com/): High performance, high class web development for Node.js.
- [socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io-node): Socket.IO aims to make realtime apps possible in every browser and mobile device, blurring the differences between the different transport mechanisms.

The basic of these programs are also explained with those screencasts.

Answer (score 3):

You could start with a tutorial like the one at [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/) or [the Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) for example.

There's also an introduction *video* on the homepage of node.js itself. Check that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

The ["Let's make a webapp" tutorial of dailyjs](http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa) is also a nice starting Point. And don't forget [the Node Guide](http://nodeguide.com/). There is also a free ebook called [Mastering Node](http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/) which may be interesting.